# howcome my python music discord bot sounds so bad?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, yt-dlp

I am coding a music discord bot using discord.py and YT_DLP. For some reason, the audio is distorted when I play the audio source to discord voice channel. This is part of my code:
`
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def YES(ctx, url):
if(ctx.author.voice):
channel=ctx.message.author.voice.channel
voice = await channel.connect()

```
        ydl_opts = {
            'format': "bestaudio",
            'ffmpeg_location': os.path.realpath("C:/Code/Side projects/discord bot/ffmpeg/bin/"),
            'postprocessors': [{
                'key': "FFmpegExtractAudio",
                'preferredcodec': "mp3",
                'preferredquality': "192",
            }],
            'noplaylist':'True',
        }

        #with yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
            #ydl.download([url])

        name = "payphone.mp3" #i hardcoded the audio file to payphone so i dont have to keep downloading
        voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(name, executable="C:\\Code\\Side projects\\discord bot\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe"))
    else:
        await ctx.send("Get in a voice channel first")`
```

I thought it was the audio source file that was bad, but the source file sounded totally fine to me when I was using an mp3 player. Then I was wondering if it was the bitrate. I tried changing the bitrate but it still doesn't work. My internet is pretty good (70mbps download and 1.7mbps upload).

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind yall, the audio was distorted because of the bot's volume. I set the bot's volume on 200% in discord, I guess there is a threshold for the volume before it becomes distorted.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [answer], and do not use the answer section to acknowledge a problem outside the code, a typo or other such problem that's specific to your own setup (which in a sense invalidates the question). If you have a follow-up question (for example, "why does increasing the volume on an audio file result in distortion?"), that could be asked separately, if it were on topic (although I think that's more of a general computer science question; and I think you should be able to answer it for yourself by *looking at the file in an audio editor* and boosting volume there).

Comment: But generally it's important to understand that this is **not a discussion forum**, and we don't try to find problems here. You are expected to diagnose the issue **before** posting - and isolate a cause well enough to produce a [mre] that you are confident others can use to see the problem locally. That is to say, proper "debugging questions" on Stack Overflow are not "what is wrong with my code?", but "why does this specific part of the code specifically do X, when I expected Y instead?" (and X and Y should be reproducible, and objectively measurable).

Comment: Got it, my apologies.